# Find Y value of an interpolated point in a Linestring given an X value on Postgis

Tags: interpolation, postgis

I would like to know what's the best way to find the `Y` value of an interpolated point inside the `Linestring`, when given the `X`.

The `X` coordinates of my input `Linestring` will always be incremental and non sequential (as in the example below). The `Y` values could be any real number.

```
LINESTRING(223 -59,228 -59.3,233 -59.7,242 -60,263 -60.4,
           268 -61.7,275 -62.1,280 -62.5)
```

Given an `X` value (let's say `270` for example), the query would output the interpolated value inside the `Linestring` (in this case it would be `-61.81428571`, using points `[268 -61.7]` and `[275 -62.1]` for the interpolation)

If the `X` value already belongs to the `Linestring`, the it would just output its corresponding `Y` value. `268: -61.7`

The input table will just have a single column with a single row with the linestring.
The `X` value would be part of the query.

I'm using PostGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way will be to generate a vertical line and check intersection between it and the geom. It will be good to make sure the line is as long as the bounding box of the linestring.

```
SELECT ST_INTERSECTION(geom, ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(268, ST_YMin(geom)), ST_MakePoint(268,ST_YMax(geom)))) 
FROM
    linestrings;
```

Comment: Further note that there may be a wide range of other types other than `POINT` from this method, depending if there are 0 or more solutions (intersections).